# Multi-threading isn't speeding up programme

Tags: multithreading

I'm trying to do a school project for which I'm using multi-threading because if not it stops responding

I tried to multi-thread it isn't doing much the app still lags out. I also tried to put all the voice-related commands in functions. The app starts up but once I click on the mic button the app stops responding.

```
from requests.models import Response
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import tkinter
from tkinter import Canvas, Frame, Image, Label, StringVar, Tk, font
from tkinter.constants import ANCHOR, BOTTOM, E, END, GROOVE, RAISED, RIDGE, RIGHT, SUNKEN, TOP, W, Y
from typing import Text
import threading




window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("App name")
window.geometry("320x640")
f = Frame(window)
x = f.grid_size()

# Add image file
bg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "backgroundf.png")
# Show image using label
background = tkinter.Label( window, image = bg)
background.place(x = 0, y = 0)

userimg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'user1.png')
userlabel = tkinter.Label(window, image = userimg, bg = '#3D4154')
userlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=E,pady=(50,0))

window.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)


listener = sr.Recognizer() #Listener for the speech recoginition module
engine = pyttsx3.init() #Engine for Pythontts
voices = engine.getProperty('voices') #get a property called voice form the sr module
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id) #Set the properties of the voice

def voicerecog():
    with sr.Microphone() as source: #mic = source
            listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1) #According to Background noise it changes.
            Atxt.set("Listening...")
            voice = listener.listen(source) #the listener will listen to the source
            v = listener.recognize_google(voice) #To convert the speech to using google api
            return v

choice = None
def clicked():
    global choice
    choice = "Clicked"

def mic():
    while True:
        global choice
        if choice == "Clicked":
            d = voicerecog()
            return d


Utxt = tkinter.StringVar()
Utxt.set("User Text Here")
text = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable = Utxt, bg = "#8B7DF6", wraplength= 250, pady = 1, padx = 1, fg = '#020402')
text.grid(row = 1, column=1, sticky=E)

Atxt = tkinter.StringVar()
Atxt.set("Assistant Reply here")
text1 = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable = Atxt, wraplength= 250, pady = 1, padx = 1, bg = '#8B7DF6',fg = '#020402')
text1.grid(row = 2, column=0, sticky = W)

window.resizable(0, 0)


def coronavirus_update(region = 'global'):
    ''' returns graph of coronavirus in different countries'''
    import requests
    import shutil
    url = 'https://corona.dnsforfamily.com/graph.png?c='
    r = requests.get(url + region, stream = True)
    filename = 'graph.png'
    if r.status_code == 200:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
        return 'Image sucessfully Downloaded: ',filename
    else:
        return 'Image Couldn\'t be retreived'



def speak(message):
    engine.say(message)
    engine.runAndWait()



def clicked():
    while True:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source: #mic = source
                st ="updates"
                if "updates" in st:
                    msg = "Please tell your country code"
                    speak(msg)
                    t = threading.Thread(target=voicerecog)
                    t.start()
                    countryid = t
                    t.join()
                    speak(coronavirus_update(countryid)) 
        except:
            speak("Failed recoginizing your voice")

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "mic.png")
micbtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo, bg = '#8B7DF6', fg = "#8B7DF6" ,border = 0, command = clicked).place(x = 155,y=580)

window.mainloop()
```

Since the speech to text usually lags the app out I decided to multithread it.
Any better approach will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You know that Python uses a global interpreter lock? https://realpython.com/python-gil/ that prevents parallel execution of threads?

Comment: ohh damn that's sad, ig I have to go with removing the GUI, Thanks tho.

Comment: I'm no Python expert, but perhaps there are some ways to deal with it.

Comment: Of removing the GIL??

Comment: I doubt the GIL can be removed. But perhaps there are alternative solutions. I'm by no means a Python expert.

Comment: @PhantomGaming: you can't remove the GIL, it's a fundamental part of how python works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your support in the comments.

I still couldn't multithreaded it.
What I could do is I removed the while true loop which resulted in the programme working, maybe the loop was the main cause I still couldn't figure out why but it works!!!

In short, removing the while loop fixed it.